# How to completely change node/entity rendering to my own render element using hook_entity_build_defaults_alter()

Tags: nodes, hooks, 9

I want to interrupt the normal entity view build process for certain content type and view mode combination, and use a custom render array instead of the default node builder render array.

I can almost get there using the following:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_build_defaults_alter().
 */
function custom_node_build_defaults_alter(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, $view_mode) {
  if ($view_mode === 'my_special_view_mode') {
    $build = [
      '#type' => 'my_special_element',
      '#thing1' => $node->get('my_field')->getValue(),
      '#cache' => $build['#cache'],
    ];
  }
}
```

This hook is invoked by `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder::viewMultiple()`. but then `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder::view()` immediately prevents it from working because it manually adds in its own `#pre_render` hook...

```php
  public function view(EntityInterface $entity, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    $build_list = $this->viewMultiple([$entity], $view_mode, $langcode);

    // The default ::buildMultiple() #pre_render callback won't run, because we
    // extract a child element of the default renderable array. Thus we must
    // assign an alternative #pre_render callback that applies the necessary
    // transformations and then still calls ::buildMultiple().
    $build = $build_list[0];
    $build['#pre_render'][] = [$this, 'build'];

    return $build;
  }
```

...which means that when we get to rendering in `\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer::doRender()`, because there has been a pre_render hook added manually, my render element's pre_render hook gets ignored due to the simple array merge:

```php
    // If the default values for this element have not been loaded yet, populate
    // them.
    if (isset($elements['#type']) && empty($elements['#defaults_loaded'])) {
      $elements += $this->elementInfo->getInfo($elements['#type']);
    }
```

Comment: Note that I cannot just override NodeViewBuilder, since it's very conditional to certain view modes only.

Comment: I have also tried overriding the view_builder handler using hook_entity_bundle_info_alter() but I don't think you can override handlers there.

Comment: You can extend NodeViewBuilder, the view mode is an argument of both methods you want to override, so writing conditional code to certain view modes would be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write a view builder handler decorator.

```
function foobar_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_type = $entity_types['node'];
  $entity_type->set('foobar_original_viewer_class', $entity_type->getViewBuilderClass());
  $entity_type->setViewBuilderClass(FoobarNodeViewBuilder::class);
}
```

```
class FoobarNodeViewBuilder implements EntityHandlerInterface, EntityViewBuilderInterface, TrustedCallbackInterface {

  public function __construct(EntityHandlerInterface|EntityViewBuilderInterface|TrustedCallbackInterface $originalHandler);

  public static function createInstance(ContainerInterface $container, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    return new static($container->get('entity_type.manager')
      ->createHandlerInstance($entity_type->get('foobar_original_viewer_class'), $entity_type)
  }

  public function view(EntityInterface $entity, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    return $this->originalHandler->view($entity, $view_mode, $langcode);
  }

}
```

(If PHP 8 is not available then just rewrite the constructor without union types and property promotion.)

You will, of course, want to do this for every method of the interfaces being implemented, I am too lazy to type it in. Now in `view` you have complete power as to what happens.

For tidier code, move the string `foobar_original_viewer_class` into a class constant.

Comment: So I think my problem with this is it's not limited limited to nodes, it could be any entity type, and I don't know what they could be ahead of time. The logic is based on using a view mode that starts with a specific prefix, for example, `design_system_render_element_id`. Do I really want to decorate *every* entity type's view builder?

Comment: How does this work if my module's hook runs before layout_builder_entity_type_alter(), which also overrides the view builder class itself, without decoration?

Comment: You could indeed decorate every entity type view builder. It just costs a loop in `foobar_entity_type_alter` the class is not specific to entity type at all. It implements interfaces. As for layout, it does not change the setViewBuilderClass as far as I can see. In fact, I do not see any `setViewBuilderClass` calls anywhere.

Comment: I have been working my way through a similar problem. It seemed like a simple enough proposition to render a node as custom render element and maybe even a good pattern too, since the render element is for a card component, which we use extensively in our system. To get around the limitation you encountered, we ended up manually called the `preRender` method at the end of our manual build process: https://github.com/uiowa/uiowa/blob/1f3a4baf20a2e11865186f2edb8e8695ce57a5c2/docroot/modules/custom/uiowa_core/src/Entity/NodeBundleBase.php#L76

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have a solution now that didn't involve overriding the view builder class for every entity type on the site, because the logic is solely based on view mode names:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_build_defaults_alter().
 */
function custom_entity_build_defaults_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity) {
  // When using a view mode that starts with component override the entity build
  // process to generate a component render element instead.
  if ($entity instanceof FieldableEntityInterface && strpos($build['#view_mode'], 'component_') === 0) {
    $build['#component_render_element'] = determineTheRenderElementFromViewMode($build['#view_mode']);
    // Remove the default theme set by \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder::getBuildDefaults()
    unset($build['#theme']);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter().
 */
function custom_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if (isset($build['#component_render_element'])) {
    // Generate the component render element.
    $build['component_render_element'] = [
      // In this example, view mode matches 1:1 with a render element.
      '#type' => $build['#component_render_element'],
      '#label' => $entity->label(),
      '#url' => $entity->toUrl(),
      ...
    ];
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter().
 */
function custom_entity_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if (isset($build['component_render_element'])) {
    // Hide any fields on the build array other than our render element.
    foreach (Element::getVisibleChildren($build) as $key) {
      if ($key !== 'component_render_element') {
        $build[$key]['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now this would have been a lot easier if I wasn't using render elements, and instead just used `#theme` for these elements because I could probably do all the logic inside custom_entity_build_defaults_alter(). The tricky part was undoing #theme, and adding a #type, but dealing with the fact that entity rendering happens in two parts, one early that adds a pre-render callback, and then the actual entity rendering in the pre-render callback itself.

I also found this strange in `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder::buildComponents`, likely going to file a bug report:

```
    // Let the displays build their render arrays.
    foreach ($entities_by_bundle as $bundle => $bundle_entities) {
      $display_build = $displays[$bundle]->buildMultiple($bundle_entities);
      foreach ($bundle_entities as $id => $entity) {
        $build[$id] += $display_build[$id];
      }
    }
```

Because of the simple array merge, the build defaults *always* take precedence over the actual display build render arrays, which is the opposite of what I would expect.